# Pagination, items per page dependant on number of results (PHP)

Tags: php, pagination

long time lurker first time asker.

I'm trying to piece together a pagination function that will take into account the total amount of items and increase the results per page to ensure each page is fully populated.

For example if I had 35 results and I wanted a minimum of 10 results per page it would ideally return 12, 12 & 11 results per page.

Clearly my logic-fu is weak because I for the life of me cannot seem to comprehend this seemingly simple task. Embarrassing (it pains me to ask) as I've been at this for a week now and I know there's a simple answer to this.

I'm not necessarily asking for a solution (though that would be appreciated) as a hint in the right direction may be all I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have at least 10 items (test it) :

```
nbPages = floor(nbItems/10)

nbItemsPerPageMax = 10 + ceil((nbItems - 10*nbPages)/nbPages)
```

You won't need to adjust for the last page as the `limit` clause don't need the exact number or items in this case (just use `limit numPage*nbItemsPerPageMax, nbItemsPerPageMax`).

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to write query like this and use `LIMIT` for limiting how much you wabt to show result out of all result.

```
select * from table where condition LIMIT 0,12
```